# Application cannot launch by clicking on a file in Android

Tags: android, intentfilter

I want to launch my app when a user click on the file. So I have written below codes:

```
<intent-filter
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/public_app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

    <data
        android:host="*"
        android:mimeType="application/ava"
        android:pathPattern=".*\\.ava"
        android:scheme="file"/>
</intent-filter>
```

But it didn't work! I have used it before and it worked perfectly.
What should I do for working it?

**Edit:** 
When installing an application from AppStore, the launcher in addition android installer, show my app! whereas I want show it when click on ava files.

Comment: Tried escaping that backslash in `pathPattern`? `.*\\.ava`?

Comment: I've tried it but not working :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<activity name="com.your.activity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ava" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks @Harash Chhelana, I've tried it but not working. I think we should change something else out of Manifest file. shouldn't we?

Comment: finally, I can do it.